# maven using the wrong url for repo

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I created a jenkins job for my spring batch service.

When I ran the job it throws error "Could not resolve dependencies for project"

When I checked the URLs that the maven is using to download artifacts it adds a content in the URL which is not supposed to be there.

The below URLS lead to 404 but if I remove the content from the URL the Jar/pom is present.

Downloading: https://clojars.org/repo/content/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.5/commons-lang-2.5.pom

Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/content/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.5/commons-lang-2.5.pom

Where is this content coming from?

Comment: Some content may fail to download especially from unknown sources.

Comment: What repositories are configured in settings.xml used by Maven?

Answer (score -1):

What are the configurations added in the maven settings.xml file?

There could be some problem in the repo that the maven is accessing. Try checking the configurations in settings.xml